# Excel does not work when ssis package deployed on server

Tags: excel, ssis, package

I have SSIS package that imports excel data . When I ran the package locally it works but when I deploy it to server I get the following error.
''The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft OLEDB.4.0 is not registered. If the 64 bit driver is not installed run the package in 32 bit mode .''

To solve the problem , I have installed a 64 bit  driver access database Engin. I have also changed run 64 bit to false under solution property.
does anyone has a suggestions?

Comment: Imports excel data to what destination?

Comment: Excel to SQl Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run64BitRuntime(Default true) under project property is a Visual Studio environment setting, and doesn't apply to packages run outside of BIDS. 
[image]

If at all you need to run the package with 32 bits outside BIDS, then enable 32 bit runtime under SQL server jobs -> General tab
[image]

Comment: The 64 bit Driver has to be installed on local machine as well as the server SSIS package is going to be deployed at.

Comment: I agree. As I mentioned in my answer - if you want to run package with 32 bits, then enable 32 bit runtime under SQL server jobs -> General tab which should be enough. For 64 bit need to have supporting drivers and you can ignore the above changes since packages by default are 64 bit.